# Printing Nested JSON Data

Tags: python, json

I am new to programming. I am working with some data that I got using the requests library.  I saved the response to a separate file.  The response has a lot of company information that I don't want to print.  I only want certain types of company data.

The problem I am having is with a nested key/value.  I can access the key/value "Years in Business" from the first company in the list just fine, but the issue is that the key/value from the first company in the list is being copied for each company in the data file.

Here is the data (modified for this post) I'm working with:

```json
{
  "result": [
    {
      "info": [
        {
          "company_name": "Apples Company",
          "country_name": "America",
          "date_founded": "2018-04-01",
          "company_descr": "We sell apples.",
          "add_info": [
            {
              "years_in_business": "Over 20",
              "owns building": "Yes"
            }
          ],
          "add_data": [
            {
              "some_data_1_ID": "A0w8eed37rtfx",
              "some_data_2": "Value"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "company_name": "Car Company",
          "country_name": "Spain",
          "date_founded": "2012-08-09",
          "company_descr": "We sell cars",
          "add_info": [
            {
              "years_in_business": "Over 50",
              "owns building": "No"
            }
          ],
          "add_data": [
            {
              "some_data_1_ID": "Bsadf4trets77",
              "some_data_2": "No Value"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "company_name": "Pie Company",
          "country_name": "Germany",
          "date_founded": "1900-04-30",
          "company_descr": "We sell Pies.",
          "add_info": [
            {
              "years_in_business": "Over 100",
              "owns building": "Yes"
            }
          ],
          "add_data": [
            {
              "some_data_1_ID": "e64hfg6666",
              "some_data_2": "Value"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is my code:

```
import json

with open('company_info.json', encoding='utf8') as file:
    company_data = json.load(file)

for key in company_data['result'][0]['info']:
    print('Company Name: ' + key.get('company_name'))
    print('Country Name: ' + key.get('country_name'))
    print('Date Founded: ' + key.get('date_founded'))
    print('Years in Business: ' + company_data['result'][0]['info'][0]
    ['add_info'][0]['years_in_business'])
```

Here is the output:

```
Company Name: Apples Company
Country Name: America
Date Founded: 2018-04-01
Years in Business: Over 20
Company Name: Car Company
Country Name: Spain
Date Founded: 2012-08-09
Years in Business: Over 20
Company Name: Pie Company
Country Name: Germany
Date Founded: 1900-04-30
Years in Business: Over 20

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should iterate for `'years_in_business'` just like the others:

```
for key in company_data['result'][0]['info']:
    print('Company Name: ' + key.get('company_name'))
    print('Country Name: ' + key.get('country_name'))
    print('Date Founded: ' + key.get('date_founded'))
    print('Years in Business: ' + key.get('add_info')[0]['years_in_business'])

#Output:
Company Name: Apples Company
Country Name: America
Date Founded: 2018-04-01
Years in Business: Over 20
Company Name: Car Company
Country Name: Spain
Date Founded: 2012-08-09
Years in Business: Over 50
Company Name: Pie Company
Country Name: Germany
Date Founded: 1900-04-30
Years in Business: Over 100
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `enumerate` to access to the `index` and `value` of your list element at the same time:

```
for index, key in enumerate(company_data['result'][0]['info']):
    print('Company Name: ' + key.get('company_name'))
    print('Country Name: ' + key.get('country_name'))
    print('Date Founded: ' + key.get('date_founded'))
    print('Years in Business: ' + company_data['result'][0]['info'][index] 
    ['add_info'][0]['years_in_business'])
```

Answer (score 0):

you ned to extract that value from list from keys on same level so other key dict keys are

```
for key in company_data['result'][0]['info']:
    print('Company Name: ' + key.get('company_name'))
    print('Country Name: ' + key.get('country_name'))
    print('Date Founded: ' + key.get('date_founded'))
    print('Years in Business: ' + key['add_info'][0]['years_in_business'])
```

Answer (score 0):

To print the information for all the companies, you iterate of the list of them using  something like this:

```
import json

with open('company_info.json', encoding='utf8') as file:
    company_data = json.load(file)

for company in company_data['result'][0]['info']:
    print('Company Name: ' + company.get('company_name'))
    print('Country Name: ' + company.get('country_name'))
    print('Date Founded: ' + company.get('date_founded'))
    print('Years in Business: '
            + company.get('add_info')[0]['years_in_business'])
    print()
```

Output:

```
Company Name: Apples Company
Country Name: America
Date Founded: 2018-04-01
Years in Business: Over 20

Company Name: Car Company
Country Name: Spain
Date Founded: 2012-08-09
Years in Business: Over 50

Company Name: Pie Company
Country Name: Germany
Date Founded: 1900-04-30
Years in Business: Over 100
```